# Eclipse minimizes automatically the console tab

Tags: java, eclipse

Okay, Something strange happens now with eclipse.

Everytime I click to open the console window, eclipse closes it automatically.

[image: console window minimize automatically]

Comment: +Cristian Ceron try restarting

Comment: @TheProgrammer already restarted the PC, didn't work.

Comment: Create a simple app with S.O.P. and see what it does

Comment: @programmersdude I have another workspace where eclipse works fine, really dunno what to do.

Comment: Is your eclipse latest version?

Comment: 4.5.1 eclipse mars 1 Release

Comment: @Cristian Ceron I forgot in SO it's @ not +. XD

Comment: @Cristian Ceron Also, try going to Java Perspective, not Debug.

Comment: Same here and it's really frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your perspective. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (eventually) was to switch perspective, then open the Console, then switch back to the original perspective.
(Sort it out Eclipse)